# Prevent PowerShell from automatically passing my Windows username to "ssh"

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, putty

How do I prevent PowerShell from entering my Windows username as the user in `ssh`?
I try to access OctoPi for instance. I open PowerShell. I enter:

```
ssh octopi.local
```

PowerShell then returns:

```
[username]@octopi.local's password:
```

(note: username hidden for privacy purposes).

Of course, I can never login this way, because that user doesn't exist on the Raspberry Pi!

When I do this using PuTTY, I am correctly prompted to enter the username:

```
login as: pi
pi@octopi.local's password:
Linux octopi 5.4.79-v7+ #1373 SMP Mon Nov 23 13:22:33 GMT 2020 armv7l
```

Why would PowerShell assume that I want to pass my Windows username to something I'm logging into? How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the desired username on the `ssh` commandline:

```
ssh user@example.com
```

---

*(btw, this is not a PowerShell question, you are just using OpenSSH `ssh` client)*